# Is it safe to completely replace `npm` with `yarn`?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I've noticed that many open-source projects are beginning to use `yarn` instead of `npm install`, and the list of yarn's advantages looks impressive indeed. Though, almost no one is using, say, `yarn start` instead of `npm start`.

So, my question is: can i replace all `npm something` commands with `yarn something` and remove `npm` completely from my system and servers?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's fine.

I'm not sure exectly what are your concernces so my answer is very short ;)

Answer (score -4):

I would say check in the [yarn docs](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs) and make sure if all the commands are same. If yes then you can replace the "npm" with "yarn". And make sure to test everything thoroughly.

But in my personal opinion, you should just leave it like it is. Because as long as npm is doing what you need, you are just taking a risk to break something (by removing npm). You can always try yarn in the next project and see how it goes.

The only time it will make sense to remove npm from an existing project. And replace with something else is, If you are trying to do something which npm does not allow you to but the other tool does.

Comment: I would disagree with your point about leaving it like it is. Give yarn a shot and see if it works for you. It's pretty stable at this point (Oct 2017), and I still find it faster than npm, despite npm's recent improvements. That said, don't actually *remove* npm, because you may still need it for other things.